# Historico de edições de um modelo Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gostaria de saber como posso criar um histórico com todas as edições realizadas em um modelo, em ruby on rails.

Answer (score 2):

Existem [várias gems de versionamento de registros](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning). A mais conhecida é a [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). Essa gem cria uma tabela que grava o histórico de todas as alterações dos modelos monitorados, inclusive pode associar ao usuário que fez a alteração.

Adicionar o PaperTrail em seu projeto é bem simples. Basta incluir `gem 'paper_trail'` no Gemfile, criar a [tabela de versionamento](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/airblade/paper_trail/master/lib/generators/paper_trail/templates/create_versions.rb), e adicionar `has_paper_trail` nas classes que deseja versionar.